# On an online video chat, should we say "I go back to you later" or "I come back to you later"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Ok, let see this scenario.

You are an online English teacher & you are teaching a student online. The student got some technical issue & you need to wait for a while until he fixes his problem. You then say "**I go back to you later**" or "**I come back to you later**".

Some people say "**I go back to you later**" and others say "**I come back to you later**".

I think the correct saying is "**I go back to you later**" because the speaker will move far away his position.

**Is that correct?**

Answer (score 4):

Normally you would say:

> I **will come** back to you later.

if you are staying on the connection (internet or phone).

If you will drop the connection to resume later on, then:

> I **will get** back to you later.

This also works in personal communication. Let's say you ask your professor something, but he needs to speak to another student first. He might say to you:

> I **will** come back to you later.

When he does, let's say he needs to do some research back at his office before he can answer. In that case:

> I **will** get back to you later.

Some people might use "later *on*", but it is unnecessary.

Comment: If I was staying on the connection, I think it would be more idiomatic to say, "I'll be right back." (Or, if it might be awhile, something like, "I'll be back in a little while.")

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user3169. There are many places where, we still practice the wrong usage as it's habituated and sounds good. But actually, the correct way may be completely different.

You could say,

> I **will get** back to you later *or* I **will talk** to you later